# Existence of real solutions to nonlinear algebraic equation: conditions on coefficients

Tags: existence-theorems, algebraic-equations

Good day. I am dealing with the following system of nonlinear algebraic equations:

$$
x_j = \prod_{k=1}^N (1 + x_k)^{A_{j,k}}\,,\quad j=1,\ldots,N\,,
$$

where $A_{j,k}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I would like to determine the necessary conditions on the matrix $A$ for which the system admits at least one solution with $x_j\in\mathbb{R}_+\cup\{\infty\}\,,\;\forall j$.

The only case I was able to deal with is the trivial one $N=1$. In this case it is simple to see that the equation

$$
x = (1 + x)^A\,,
$$
admits real, positive solutions only if $A\leq1$ (when $A=1$ the solution is $1/x=0$).

Comment: Probably it should be $A_{k,j}$ in the power.

Comment: You’re right! Thanks for pointing this out. Fixed it.